# Removing specific matching substring from a string python

Tags: python

I want to remove a matching substring from a string in python .

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
abc= "20160622125255102D87Z2"

if "Z2" in abc:
    abc.rstrip("Z2")
    print(abc)
```

But this doesn't work. Kindly help

Comment: Use [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/string.html#string.replace), `abc = abc.replace("Z2", '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rstrip()` returns a new string; it does not modify the existing string.

You have to reassign abc to contain the new string:

```
abc = abc.rstrip("Z2")
```

Comment: Thank you ! Gotcha

Answer (score 1):

It's because rstrip returns a new string. Try

```
abc = abc.rstrip("Z2")
```

Also, if the substring you want to remove could appear anywhere in the string (as opposed to being at the end always), you might instead want to use

`abc.replace("Z2","")`

Comment: For my case , the substring occurs at the end , so i used rstrip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions. Which will remove `Z2` from the end as well as cases where it's somewhere in the string.

```
import re
abc= "20160622125255102D87Z2"
abc = re.sub('Z2', '', abc)
print(abc)
```

Comment: Thanks you, got it !

Comment: Dumping code without an explanation is not helpful for either the questioner or future readers.